# Exchange 2010 forward outgoing domain emails to a internal IP

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I want forward to a internal email server, all outgoing email to test.com domain...

Internal email server is a linux server...
I have exchange and linux email server(postfix) with different domains, I need forward the emails from my exchange server to the linux server internal IP, the target domain is a .com domain.

How can I do that? is possible?

outgoing emails to test.com->send to 172.16.3.34 server

Comment: so... what is your question?

Comment: sorry, question edited..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by creating an additional Send Connector in Exchange.  You probably already have a generic catch-all one that specifies an address space of '*', and is configured to determine the destination server based on a DNS lookup of the MX record.

You just need to create an additional one with an address space of "test.com", with the option "route mail through the following smart host" configured with your Postfix server 172.16.3.34.